# What is the correct order to install SharePoint 2013 SP or CU on mutli-tier servers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update

We are planning to install CU on SharePoint 2013 farm and we have the following types of servers:

- 5 WFEs
- 4 APP (running CA)
- 2 Search Query
- 2 Search
- 2 Distributed Cache

I was wondering what would be the correct order to install CU on which servers first, and same also for running the configuration wizard.

The plan is since we have too many servers, is to apply the CU in parallel to all servers to save time, and then run the configuration wizard, but I don't know if there is a recommended order to run the configuration wizard (for example do we need to run it on APP servers or Distributed Cache or WFE)?

I would like to see MS document or best practices in regards to the CU patching if all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the CU bits in parrellel on all server in farm to avoid the long wait time, But for the config wizard you cannot run more than 1 thread. As per my personal experince, i always start from Central admin and then followed by other Apps servers and WFE at the end.

Please have a look on this answer.
[Recommended way to install CU and Update on SharePoint Servers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145829/recommended-way-to-install-cu-and-update-on-sharepoint-servers/145841#145841)

[Why SharePoint 2013 Cumulative Update takes 5 hours to install?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/04/01/why-sharepoint-2013-cumulative-update-takes-5-hours-to-install.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage)

[How to install update packages on a SharePoint farm where search component and high availability search topologies are enabled](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/03/13/how-to-install-update-packages-on-a-sharepoint-farm-where-search-component-and-high-availability-search-topologies-are-enabled.aspx)